# Вылетает приложение при обновлении версии БД

Tags: android, android-room

Есть приложение, которое использовало версию БД 1, было написано используя `SQLOpenHelper`. Переписал приложение используя `Room`, поднял версию БД, и написал миграцию, но на Android 9, при запуске приложения вылетает и выдает ошибку

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: plants (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO plants_new (_id, rus_name, lat_name, en_name, other_name, classification, season, description, categoryid, category, icon, img,favorites)SELECT _id, rus_name, lat_name, en_name, other_name, classification, season, description, categoryid, category, icon, img,favorites FROM plants
```

Хотя на том же Android 8 все работает и на более ранних версиях все работает. В чем может быть проблема на 9-ом андроид?

Вот код класса `AppDatabase`. Где я создаю новую таблицу, переношу данные из старой таблицы в новую и переименовываю таблицу `plants_new`

```
@Database(entities = {Plant.class}, version = 2, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AppDatabase instance;

    public abstract PlantDao plantDao();

    private static final String DB_NAME = "medplants.db";

    private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1,2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            // Create the new table
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE plants_new (_id INTEGER NOT NULL, rus_name Text, lat_name Text, " +
                    "en_name Text, other_name Text, classification Text, season Text, description Text, " +
                    "categoryid Integer, category Text, icon Text, img Text, favorites Integer, PRIMARY KEY(_id))");
            // Copy the data
            database.execSQL(
                    "INSERT INTO plants_new (_id, rus_name, lat_name, en_name, other_name, classification, season, description, categoryid, category, icon, img,favorites)" +
                            "SELECT _id, rus_name, lat_name, en_name, other_name, classification, season, description, categoryid, category, icon, img, favorites FROM plants");
            // Remove the old table
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE plants");
            // Change the table name to the correct one
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE plants_new RENAME TO plants");
        }
    };


    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                    .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
                    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Если с нуля установить приложение, то все нормально. Проблема когда была установлена предыдущая версия и после обновления приложения пытаюсь запустить.

Comment: `no such table: plants` не найдена таблица, разбирайтесь почему ее там нет.

Comment: Понимаю что ее нет. Я вот думаю может причина в следующем: Была установлена старая версия приложения с БД версии = 1, но на этом устройстве оно не запускалось, потому что код работы с БД не был переделан для андроид 9, а затем я переписал все, перевел на Room, поднял версию и написал миграцию и в этом случае приложение не может найти таблицу plants.. Скорее всего потому что БД вообще не было создано, а после обновления приложения пытается найти ее. Только такое на ум приходит

Comment: Причина как обычно проста, если делается обновление БД, а после миграция, то код по обновлению и миграции должен быть во всех новых версиях приложения, иначе когда пользователь который ни разу за 2 года не обновлял приложение - после обновление у него может всё поломаться.